# Is SQLite really faster than MySQL ?

Tags: mysql, performance, sqlite

Earlier I was planning on using MySQL for doing some analysis on Netflix and Twitter data. Then I thought of giving SQLite a try. Till now my experience has been :

1. Ratio of time to load data from a file with 100,480,057 rows & 4 columns into a DB : 
   MySQL:sqLite :: 1:1.6
2. Ratio of time to create an index on a given column : 
   MySQL:sqLite :: 1:3
3. Ratio of dropping a table  ( I made a mistake and wanted to drop and restart ) :

The difference is huge. It took a lot of time to drop a table in SQLite.

I was under the impression that SQLite faster than MySQL while providing most of the functionalities needed for a normal set of tasks. What am I missing ??

Comment: Quicker to set up, maybe... Not sure there's any other way in which it's likely to be faster, especially since you need a whole-database lock to write a single row.

Comment: SQLite does not support high concurrency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What made you think that SQLite is faster than MySQL?

I think, the very basic answer to your question would be that the amount of data you're trying to process fits better to MySQL

Comment: And this is why you shouldn't link to external, in this case not even to internal resources.. (without quoting them)

Comment: the `SQLite vs MySQL` link is dead

Answer (score 3):

See this link: http://www.sqlite.org/speed.html

**Note: It's very out of date**

In particular, notice that dropping tables is very slow (which explains 3.)

Also, all the tests are on relatively small datasets. I imagine most of the speedup would be due to lower latency, but I couldn't say for sure.

Also hard disk speed is likely to be a big factor, I imagine you could get a lot of speedup using an SSD